# Is it possible to say the cardinality of subset $\le$ set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

Let’s say I have a set $X$ and a set $Y$, and $X \subseteq Y$. Is it possible to state that $|X| \leq |Y|$ ($|X|$ cardinality of $X$)? How can I demonstrate that?

Comment: No, they could be equal.

Comment: `\leq` produces $\leq$

Comment: Thank you! Fixed.

Comment: As for demonstrating it, the identity mapping shows that $|X| \leq |Y|$.

Comment: Well, it is true but before we can *say* it is true we have to define what it means.  What *does* $|X|\le |Y|$ mean?  I believe, most text define it as: there exist an injection from $X\to Y$.  And if $X\subseteq Y$ then the identity function restricted to $X$ is an injection for $X \to Y$ so it would have to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only can you say it, you can prove it!

Recall the definitions: for sets $A$ and $B$, we say that

- $|A|\leq |B|$ if and only if there exists a one-to-one function $f\colon A\to B$;
- $|A|=|B|$ if and only if there exists a bijective function $f\colon A\to B$;
- $|A|\lt |B|$ if and only if $|A|\leq |B|$ and $|A|\neq|B|$; that is, if and only if there is an injection $f\colon A\to B$ but no bijection $f\colon A\to B$.

(In the presence of the Axiom of Choice, you get more equivalences; for example, $|A|\lt |B|$ if and only if there is an injection $A\to B$ but no surjection $A\to B$; and $|A|\geq |B|$ if and only if there is a surjection $A\to B$; and more).

To prove that if $A\subseteq B$ then $|A|\leq |B|$, then simply use the inclusion function $\iota\colon A\to B$ given by $\iota(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$. This function is injective, as $a\neq b\implies \iota(a)\neq\iota(b)$. This shows $|A|\leq|B|$.

Careful, that it is possible for $A\subset B$, $A\neq B$, yet $|A|=|B|$; the inclusion function does not prove the equality of cardinality, but other functions might. An example of this occurs with $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you! I’m trying to prove that if X is not enumerable then Y is not enumerable either. Can I use that given $|X| \leq |Y|$, then if X is not enumerable then Y isn’t either?

Comment: @JohnMyers: Yes: if $|Y|$ is enumerable/countable, then $|Y|\leq\aleph_0$, and therefore $|X|\leq |Y|\leq\aleph_0$ implies $|X|\leq \aleph_0$. By contrapositive, if $|X|\nleq \aleph_0$, then $|Y|\nleq\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. The function $\iota:X\to Y:x\mapsto x$ is an injection from $X$ to $Y$, and the existence of such an injection by definition means that $|X|\le|Y|$.

If $Y$ is a finite set, you can go further: if $X\subsetneqq Y$, then $|X|<|Y|$. If $Y$ is infinite, however, it has proper subsets of the same cardinality as itself. E.g., the set of even integers has the same cardinality as the set of integers.

Answer (score 1):

If we talk about cardinality of two sets, say $A$ and $B$, the way to show that $|A|\leq |B|$ is giving an injective function $f: A \longrightarrow B$.

Now, in your problem, since $A \subseteq B$, the function $f: A \longrightarrow B$ given by $f(x)= x$ is an injective function (If A and B are explicit sets, you can find many other injections).

As an important mark, $f$ is not the indentical function, instead of that and according the hypotesis of $A \subseteq B$, $f$ would be called "The Inclusion of A in B"

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia: "$A$ has cardinality less than or equal to the cardinality of $B$ if there exists an injective function from $A$ into $B$." (That is a definition.)

An injective function is obvious: the identity.